# Reactive Mongo Extensions: How to use $push with $each using query DSL in reactive mongo extensions

Tags: mongodb, playframework, reactive-programming, reactivemongo

I want to push list of documents in mongodb document array field. In mongodb we can use `$push` with `$each` operator, but how we can using in reactive mongo extensions. example as below:

1. This is my doucment

   `{
   "_id" : ObjectId("56cadf56c3ad8cb30223613a"),
   "locations" : [ 
           {
               "_id" : ObjectId("56cadf56c3ad8cb30223613f"),
               "fieldType" : "List",
               "locationType" : "DEFAULT",
               "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-02-22T15:43:42.929Z"),
               "value" : "Default",
               "active" : true
           }
       ]
   }`
2. list of documents want to push in "locations" attribute of above document.

   `[
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("56cae036c3ad8cb20a23614b"),
   "locationType" : "COMPANY",
   "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-02-22T15:47:26.168Z"),
   "value" : "India",
   "active" : true
   },
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("56cae036c3ad8cb20a23614b"),
   "locationType" : "COMPANY",
   "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-02-22T15:47:26.168Z"),
   "value" : "USA",
   "active" : true
   }
   ]`

Comment: What's is the query tested in the MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 0):

```
      val updateOp = Json.obj("$push"-> Json.obj("locations" -> Json.obj("$each" -> Json.toJson(locations))))
      collection.update(Json.obj("_id" -> myID), updateOp)
```

should do it for you given that 'locations' is a sequence of 'Location' which is a case class with proper json Reads and Writes. It will be pretty much the same using BSON.

BTW, maybe you want to use $addToSet here instead.